# Cannot award bounty to self? No other answers are correct

Tags: discussion, bounty

I had found a question without an accepted answer, I put a bounty on it, and answered it.

Should I not be able to award the bounty to my answer? Although I do understand that this is rather pointless, I still think that it should be possible.

None of the other answers are correct, what should I do in this situation?

Comment: This way you could attract attention with your bounty and won't loose any point when you award it to yourself. If it were possible all would do it on the answers they give.

Comment: You would gain back the rep you lost from creating the bounty. The whole point of bounties is to _lose rep for potentially more views_. If you could give it back to yourself, there would be no risk to bounties.

Comment: On the question currently, no other answers are correct or worthy of the bounty. What should be done?

Comment: Let it expire and teach yourself a lesson.

Comment: For the [specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195606/css-display-one-character-in-2-colors), judging by your answer the post is actually a duplicate. You used an answer on a different post as an answer there too.

Comment: @MathewMacLean Don't award a bounty if you don't feel that any valid recipients are deserving of it.

Comment: I'd like a walkthrough of the timeline here, just for curiosity. When did you decide you could answer the question correctly, for starters?

Comment: @MartijnPieters appears to be right.  The fact that you are duplicating another answer makes it a good candidate for downvoting.  And you have attracted twice the attention (by offering the bounty and this meta post).

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Well, he posted his answer 2 hours ago, and started the bounty 12 minutes ago.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I saw the question, answered it, then set up a bounty with "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty."

Comment: @MathewMacLean: what, exactly, did you expect the bounty to get you?

Comment: @MathewMacLean A-ha! So a copied answer is exemplary?

Comment: Wait seriously? I mean... wow.

Comment: @devnull I didn't say it was. I just included the code that they needed to solve their problem and referred them to the full answer.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what I was thinking.. :/

Comment: See also: [Lost reputation after answering my own question with bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18841/lost-reputation-after-answering-my-own-question-with-bounty)

Comment: Don't bother.  $hit happens.

Comment: So, what should I do? Edit one of the answers to make it correct then award it?

Comment: Don't know.  I'm already feeling sorry for my comment given that your answer has started to attract downvotes.

Comment: @MathewMacLean: just let it expire, unless another, better answer emerges. None of the 3 answers there now qualify for automatic awarding anyway.

Comment: @MathewMacLean No, as you've been told several times, you don't award the bounty if you don't think that any of the (applicable) answers are deserving of it.  Editing someone's answer into a completely different answer is entirely inappropriate.

Comment: Why didn't you put the bounty on the question that you asked, and award the bounty to the answer that you are copying onto duplicate posts?

Comment: Since this is just an honest blunder, I refunded your bounty and closed the question as a duplicate. Happy Friday!

Comment: @AnnaLear Thank you. I have learned my lesson big time.

Comment: +1, the question is interesting. It just occured to me that I opened a bounty but finally found an answer by myself (no other answers where given). But I understand now why we indeed shouldn't be able to get the rep back.

Comment: Dont agree. If none of the solutions are correct, why can the questioner award it to himself. Also the thread chain keep me reminding [Anyone else find the Stack Overflow community toxic?](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/7szv7i/anyone_else_find_the_stack_overflow_community/)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, you cannot award a bounty to yourself.

Bounties buy **attention**. If you could award the bounty back to yourself, that'd open a loop-hole in the system: get extra attention without actually having to pay the price for that attention.

In this case, the question you answered is actually a *duplicate of your own question*. You should have voted to close it instead of posting an answer to it. I've now flagged the question to ask a moderator to close the post as a duplicate; if you are *lucky*, the bounty is refunded when they do this.

Comment: Well, the question has been marked as a duplicate and the rep has been returned. I have learned my lesson. Thank you.

Comment: There could be a middle ground ... If, after you offer a bounty, no one comes forth with a satisfactory answer, but you keep working on it and finally you find one ... you have not benefited much from the extra attention (other than doing due diligence), but you have fulfilled the criteria of the bounty, so it would make sense to reap back at least some of the rep you spent. To avoid the loophole potential, you might get back only half the rep you offered. Granted, that would be open to abuse too. I'm not arguing for this solution ... just wishing there were a better way.